# How to replace exact string in a statment using regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, string

I have couple of insert statments like below with `STRINGDECDOE()`

```
INSERT INTO EPSG_ALIAS
   (ALIAS_CODE, OBJECT_TABLE_NAME, OBJECT_CODE, NAMING_SYSTEM_CODE, ALIAS, REMARKS) 
 VALUES 
   (1431, 'Datum', 6123, 7300, STRINGDECODE('Kartastokoordinaattij\ufffdrjestelm\ufffd (1966)'), NULL);
```

How to replace the `STRINGDECODE('Kartastokoordinaattij\ufffdrjestelm\ufffd (1966)')` with

```
e'Kartastokoordinaattij\ufffdrjestelm\ufffd (1966)'
```

Using Regular expression in java

Comment: Depends; how would single quotes be quoted? Ie, what if there is a single quote in the text?

Comment: If you only want to replace exact strings why do you think you need regular expressions?

Comment: so many insert statments are there with stringdecode function . i have to replace all those..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work even with "quoted single quotes" in the text (ie, for instance, `'It''s working'`:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN 
    = Pattern.compile("\\bSTRINGDECODE\\(('[^']*(?:''[^']*)*')\\)");

// in code:

PATTERN.matcher(theInput).replaceAll("e$1")
```

Comment: some statments have function like thisSTRINGDECODE('C\ufffdte d''Ivoire / UTM zone 30N') .

Comment: If there is a single quote in the text .wt i will do in that scenario